# Conditional generic type constructor in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, constructor, wildcard

Say you have a generic class `Foo`:

```
public class Foo<T> {

    public T Data {
        get;
        protected set;
    }

}
```

Is it possible to define a constructor that is only applicable if `T` inherits (or is) a specific type.

For instance say `T` is an `int`:

```
    public Foo () {
        this.Data = 42;
    }
```

The type constraint should be checked at *compile-time*. This might be useful for optimization. Say for instance you have an `IEnumerable<T>` and you wish to make a "cache" (since LINQ queries can be quite expensive). Now if the `IEnumerable<T>` is already an `IList<T>`, it is useful not to copy data. On the other hand if it is really a LINQ query, another constructor can store the data in an array.

---

As a workaround, one can of course inherit `Foo` (e.g. `IntFoo`) and define a constructor there:

```
public class IntFoo : Foo<int> {

    public IntFoo () {
        this.Data = 42;
    }

}
```

A problem with this approach is however that `private` data is not accessible (or one has to make it `protected`). Are there some other disadvantages, or does one is supposed to model type-specific constructors this way?

Comment: Do you mean [type constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)? The only problem with type constraints is that, frustratingly, numeric primitives don't have a useful base that you can use for restrictions.

Comment: Indeed? Why can't you define a `where ...` clause after a constructor, in that case the constructor is only "*accessible*" if the types match.

Comment: regarding your edit: I am fairly certain that you cannot check at compile time whether an `IEnumerable<T>` is an `IList<T>`. After all, you can always assign an `IList<T>` to an `IEnummerable<T>` at runtime.

Comment: +1 to HugoRune's comment - your edit completely changed the question from "quite possible to be done nicely at compile time" to "no way to do it at compile time". Consider editing change back to what looked like "specify special logic/default value based on compile time type of generic" and asking separate question about "how LINQ optimizes queries where `IEnumerable<T>` actually is `IList<T>` and if it is possible at compile time".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a trick that you could apply here. It's fexible for many scenarios.

```
internal static class FooHelper
{
    private static class DefaultData<T>
    {
        public static T Value = default(T);
    }

    static FooHelper()
    {
        DefaultData<int>.Value = 42;
        DefaultData<string>.Value = "Hello World";
    }

    // From @JeffreyZhao:
    //
    // Use a static method to trigger the static constructor automatically,
    // or we need to use RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor to make sure
    // DefaultData is corrected initialized.
    //
    // The usage of RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor is kept but commented.
    // Using GetDefault<T>() is a better approach since static Foo() would be
    // called multiple times for different generic arguments (although there's 
    // no side affect in this case).
    //
    // Thanks to @mikez for the suggestion.
    public static T GetDefault<T>()
    {
        return DefaultData<T>.Value;
    }
}

public class Foo<T>
{
    /* See the comments above.
    static Foo()
    {
        RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor(typeof(FooHelper).TypeHandle);
    }
     */

    public T Data { get; protected set }

    public Foo()
    {
        Data = FooHelper.GetDefault<T>();
    }
}
```

You could specify the default values for limited types, and the result of them would be kept to default values.

This trick has several variations in practice. In my project, we use a generic `ITypeConverter<T>` instead of the build in `TypeConverter` to avoid unnecessary boxing:

```
public interface ITypeConverter<T>
{
    bool CanConvertTo<TTarget>();
    TTarget ConvertTo(T value);
}
```

The same trick could be applied as:

```
public class LongConverter : ITypeConverter<long>
{
    private static class Op<TTarget>
    {
        public static Func<long, TTarget> ConvertTo;
    }

    static LongConverter()
    {
        Op<string>.ConvertTo = v => v.ToString();
        Op<DateTime>.ConvertTo = v => new DateTime(v);
        Op<int>.ConvertTo = v => (int)v;
    }

    public TTarget ConvertTo<TTarget>(T value)
    {
        return Op<TTarget>.ConvertTo(value);
    }
}
```

Elegant, fast and clean.

Comment: As written, that first sample is not going to work as expected. FooHelper's static constructor is never called because no instances of FooHelper are ever created and no static members are ever accessed. The nested class `FooHelper.DefaultData<T>` is accessed but this does not cause the outer class's static constructor to run.

Comment: @mikez: You're correct. I wrote the code in webpage on the fly without testing it. :) The idea here's to use a separated, non-static class to save the generic default values, so I created `FooHelper`. I've put a `RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor` statement to make sure the static consturctor of `FooHelper` would be executed in the first time we use `Foo`. Thanks.

Comment: Definitely a good trick. Another option is to make a generic method on `FooHelper`, say `GetDefault<T>()`.

Comment: @mikez: Your approach is better. The static constructor of `Foo` would be executed multiple times with different generic arguments (although there's no side affect in this case). I've edited the answer as your suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

```
  public class Foo<T>
  {
      public T Data
      {
          get;
          protected set;
      }

            public Foo()
            {
                switch (Type.GetTypeCode(Data.GetType()))
                {
                    case TypeCode.Int16:
                    case TypeCode.Int32:
                    case TypeCode.Int64:
                        Data = (T)Convert.ChangeType(42, typeof(T));
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

            }

        }
```

This way you have a constructor for a lot of types

```
public class Foo<T>
{

    public T Data
    {
        get;
        protected set;
    }

    public Foo()
    {
        switch (Type.GetTypeCode(Data.GetType()))
        {
            case TypeCode.Boolean:
                Data = ConvertValue<T>(true); 
                break;
            case TypeCode.DateTime:
                Data = ConvertValue<T>("01/01/2014"); 
                break;
            case TypeCode.Double:
                Data = ConvertValue<T>(0.5); 
                break;
            case TypeCode.Int16:
            case TypeCode.Int32:
            case TypeCode.Int64:
                Data = ConvertValue<T>(32); 
                break;
            case TypeCode.String:
                Data = ConvertValue<T>("Test");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }
    private static T ConvertValue<T>(object value)
    {
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to do so, but I hardly can see usage.

```
public class Foo<T>
{

    public T Data
    {
        get;
        protected set;
    }

    public Foo()
    {
        if (Data is int)
            Data = (T)(object)42;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Console.WriteLine("int = {0}", new Foo<int>().Data);
Console.WriteLine("double = {0}", new Foo<double>().Data);
Console.WriteLine("string = {0}", new Foo<string>().Data);
```

Output:

```
int = 42
double = 0
string =
```

Comment: In this case the type constraint is checked at runtime.

Comment: @CommuSoft: generics are not c++ templates, they are not 100% compile time.

Comment: I know, but this is something one could check at compile time, the type constraints on classes themselves are checked at compile time (if possible).

Comment: @CommuSoft: but it's not a constraint, it's a pure application logic.

Comment: The constraint is that one can only apply a certain constructor if the types match, as is the constraint that one can only use a class `Foo<T>` if `T` is specified according to the `where ...` clause.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind creator functions instead of constructors and passing parameter of that specific type as argument (for overload resolution):

```
public class Foo<T> {

  public T Data { get; private set; }

  public static Foo<T> Create(T value)
  {
     return new Foo<T> { Data = value };
  }

  public static Foo<int> From(int value)
  {
     return new Foo<int> { Data = 42 * value };
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
  void Main()
  {
    var v = Foo<int>.Create(1); 
    var s = Foo<string>.Create("test");
  }
```

Since non-generic function is preferable when multiple overloads resolve possible (in case of `Foo<int>` it would be `Create<int>(int value)` and `Create(int value)` you'll get specific override.

Note that you only can do that for specific types and can't use type restrictions since 2 generic methods with same name (like `Create<U>()`can't coexist in the same class even if restrictions on types are clearly separate (like `where U:class` and `where U:struct`).